# Date-fns: Countdown to a specific date

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm using `date-fns`. I need to create a countdown to the next 10th of the month.

For example, if today is 5th Feb, then the countdown should be to 10th Feb. If today is say 15th Feb, then it should count to 10th March, and so on.

How can I do this with `date-fns` or even with plain javascript?

Comment: How specific does your countdown need to be?  Calendar days?  Hours? Is it a full clock with a timer that is shown in a UI?

Comment: Only calendar days. I just need the countdown number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first find the target date, like this one:

```
const today = startOfToday();
let target = setDate(today, 10);
if (isBefore(target, today)) {
  target = addMonths(target, 1);
}
```

Then calculate time remaining until the target:

```
const diff = differenceInSeconds(target, new Date());
const days = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
const hours = Math.floor((diff - days * 86400) / 3600);
const minutes = Math.floor((diff - days * 86400 - hours * 3600) / 60);
const seconds = diff - days * 86400 - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
```

Use **days**, **hours**, **minutes**, **seconds** for create a countdown. Don't forget to import required functions from `date-fns`.

Comment: Since only the difference in calendar days is needed, it would be better to simply use
`differenceInCalendarDays(target, today)` after determining the correct target date.

Comment: This line is what I was trying to figure out. let target = setDate(today, 10); Thanks for the solution.