# Date-fns: Get Countdown to a specific UTC time on a specific day or date

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm using `date-fns` library. And I have a specific requirement.

Let's say I have an event every Saturday at 7am UTC.

1. If there are 24 hours left in the event, I want to say 'Coming Soon'. If more than 24 hours are left, I want to show the calendar days targeting 7am UTC of the next Saturday.
2. As soon, as it is past 7am UTC of the Saturday, it should show calendar days left to next Saturday 7am UTC.

I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

If it was to check Saturday irrespective of time, I could just use `isSaturday()`, but that's not the case, I need to target the specific UTC time on the next Saturday (7am UTC).

UPDATE: The main problem I'm facing is to define the target as the next Saturday 7am UTC. Once the target is defined, then I can use `differenceInCalendarDays()` to get the days left.

Can you please help?

Comment: Did you learn anyting from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153056/date-fns-countdown-to-a-specific-date ... at least, how to write some code? I mean, the answer you accepted is pretty much 95% of what you need to achieve this

Comment: Of course, that was really helpful. I also just updated the question. The main problem I'm facing is to define the target as the next Saturday 7am UTC, because it's not a fixed date, but always the next Saturday from today, which I'm not understanding how to define. Once the target is defined, then I can use differenceInCalendarDays() to get the days left.

Comment: In that other question, the target was 10th of the coming month. But in this case the target is 7am UTC of the coming Saturday. That's giving me a hard time.

Comment: I mean, I could give you code to get that exact time without using date-fns - it's quite simple really

Comment: Answer to main problem posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the "main problem" is quite simple without using `date-fns` - it may be **simpler** using `date-fns` but I don't know `date-fns` - so here is plain ol' javascript `Date` object solution

```js
function nextSaturday(d = new Date) {
    const next = new Date(d);
    next.setUTCDate(next.getUTCDate() + (7 - (next.getUTCDay() + 1)) % 7);
    next.setUTCHours(7, 0, 0, 0);
    if (next <= d) { // if it's currently saturday after 7AM UTC, add 7 days
        next.setUTCDate(next.getUTCDate() + 7);
    }
    return next;
}
console.log(nextSaturday(new Date).toUTCString());
// for future readers
// Saturday March 5th 2022 is a Satruday
// at 06:59:59.999 - next should be Sat, 05 Mar 2022 07:00:00 GMT
console.log(nextSaturday(new Date('2022-03-05T06:59:59.999Z')).toUTCString());
// at 07:00:00 - next should be Sat, 05 Mar 2022 07:00:00 GMT
console.log(nextSaturday(new Date('2022-03-05T07:00:00.000Z')).toUTCString());
console.log(nextSaturday(new Date('2022-05-15T07:00:00.000Z')).toUTCString());
```

Made the function so calling `nextSaturday` without an argument will use current date - but if you pass in a date it'll use that - this is just for verifying that it works

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. I was able to use nextSaturday(new Date) with differenceInCalendarDays to get the countdown.

Comment: @asanas - I rewrote it a bit, not sure which version you used ... `function nextSaturday(d = new Date) {` ... so just `nextSaturday()` will do since the default is `new Date` :p Oh, and changed `<` to `<=` ... so at exactly 7:00:00 on Saturday it will return next Saturday - modify as required

Comment: The function starts failing for future dates. For example, if I take a date in May, console.log(nextSaturday(new Date('2022-05-15T07:00:00.000Z')).toUTCString()); returns 19th May which is a Thursday, not a Saturday. May be my explanation wasn't that clear that I wanted it to always give me the upcoming Saturday from whichever date we're on.

Comment: @asanas yeah, sorry, I over complicated the "formula" - check update

Comment: Thanks so much. This is perfect! If only I could understand what's going on inside (14 - (next.getUTCDay() + 1)) % 7)

Comment: getUTCDay returns 0 for Sunday through to 6 for Saturday ... so, for 0 (Sunday), we want to add 6 days, for 1 (Monday) we want to add 5 days, for 2 (Tuesday) we want to add 4 days ... for 6 (Saturday) we want to add 0 days ... so `7 - (dayNumber + 1) % 7` that 14 should be a 7 (doesn't matter, modulo arithmetic means the result is the same, updated code)

Comment: The +1 is because Saturday(6) is one less than 7 ... for next Sunday you wouldn't need to add anything, Monday:6, Tuesday:5, Wednesday: 4 etc, however, you would need to use `14 -` instead of `7 -` to avoid negative results for getting next Monday through to Friday - because that's how modulo arithmetic works - that's the reason I used 14 - I used code in the past for "next Monday" - which I found after you alerted me to the bug in the original answer